# Animation Component Randomly Sticking on Frames

Tags: c#, animation, unity-game-engine, gameobject

Wrote a script to trigger a very quick animation ( 24 frames ) with a keypress. I want it to feel like a kick pedal with a slow recoil. I am planning on automating this process with hundreds of gameobjects so I used the Animation component as opposed to Animator.

The basic logic is that 1. animation should play at a default speed, and when it hits the end, come back at negative half speed. 2. If the animation is triggered again while it is going backwards, it should continue forward as in step 1.

The problem is that the animation gets stuck on the last frame about 20% of the time. The console prints that the frame that it gets stuck on as 0, but it shows the last frame. It also sometimes just jumps to 0 without animating backwards.
Am I missing something stupid?

```
public GameObject go;
private Animation anim;
private AnimationClip clip;
private float animationLength;
private float limit;
private float originalSpeed = 3;
private string name;


void Start(){
    anim = go.GetComponent<Animation>();
    anim.wrapMode = WrapMode.Once;
    anim.playAutomatically = false;
    clip = anim.clip;
    clip.legacy = true;
    name = anim.clip.name;
    animationLength = anim[name].length;
    anim[name].speed = 0;
    anim.Play(name);
}

void Update(){
    if(Input.GetKeyDown("1")){
        trigger();
    }
    animate();
}

void animate(){
    limit = animationLength - (animationLength/24f);
    if(anim[name].time >= limit){
        anim[name].time = limit;
        anim[name].speed = -(originalSpeed/2);
    }
}

void trigger(){
    anim[name].speed = originalSpeed;
    anim.Play(name);
}
```

Comment: Does your animation have "ExitTime" checked **off** in the Animator viewer? Does something change when you change that? Does the `WrapMode.Once` does exactly what you want and expect (http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WrapMode.Once.html, also notice the annotations about backwards playing)?

Comment: There is no 'ExitTime' because I am using <Animation>(), not <Animator>().  The annotation about backwards behavior in WrapMode.Once is what I desire. Unfortunately, it's stopping at the end or popping the animation to the beginning without playing through.